# Prevent Python function from running while certain parameters are present

Tags: python

I am making a Thumby game (basically the dinosaur google game) but I added a star powerup. The problem is that the collision detection is every frame and and soon as the Super character is downgraded (think big Mario to little Mario) the next frame is still considered a collision and that prompts the game to end.

One though is to use the collision parameters to create an overlap variable and if it's true, prevent the game from ending. The difficult part is that there is no visualization help with Thumby other than emulation in real time and that would get very tedious testing the values to see exactly which point there would be collision overlap.

Is there a way to prevent a certain set of functions from executing if another specific function has been executed?

```
SuperCharacter = False
Sprite = Star or Cactus

while(GameRunning)
    if (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and not SuperCharacter and Sprite == Cactus):
        endGame()
    elif (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and not SuperCharacter and Sprite == Star):
        SuperCharacter = True
    elif (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and SuperCharacter and Sprite == Cactus):
        SuperCharacter = False
```

So maybe:

```
    ...
        SuperCharacter = False
        prevent(endGame(), 60 frames)
```

or something like that. That would be super cool.

Google and forums and other games on the Thumby and my own tests.

Comment: Is this actual code: `Sprite = Star or Cactus` It's probably not doing what you think.

Comment: @Barmar It is not the actual code. The star or cactus sprites are determined elsewhere using random

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a `prevent_end` variable and check it before calling `endGame`:

```py
import time

SuperCharacter = False
Sprite = Star or Cactus

prevent_end = 0
timer = time.time()
while(GameRunning):
    if time.time() - timer >= 1/30: # 30 fps
        prevent_end = max(prevent_end-1, 0)
        timer = time.time()
        
    if (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and not SuperCharacter and Sprite == Cactus):
        if prevent_end == 0:
            endGame()
    elif (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and not SuperCharacter and Sprite == Star):
        SuperCharacter = True
    elif (CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x and SuperCharacter and Sprite == Cactus):
        SuperCharacter = False
        prevent_end = 60
```

---

#### Example:

```
import time

def endGame():
    print('ending game')
    
prevent_end = 60
timer = time.time()

while(True):
    if time.time() - timer >= 1/30: # 30 fps
        prevent_end = max(prevent_end-1, 0)
        timer = time.time()
        
    if prevent_end == 0:
        endGame()
        break
```

Comment: That worked but now endGame() wont execute.

Comment: @StevenDezort I wrote a simpler version and I noticed I used `min` instead of `max`.. You can try it and see if it helps. Please look at the example I attached :)

Comment: @StevenDezort I also changed the og code I posted accordingly..

Comment: It's still not working. Would you mind if I reached out to you directly and I could show you the full code? I'm on discord @ SailorPunk

Comment: It would have been better if you posted a question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

@nokla, I figured it out! You definitely pointed me in the right direction. But here is how I was able to make it work correctly:

```
collision = CharacterPos == x and SpritePos == x
frameCount = 0
superCharacter = False
sprite = star or cactus


if (not collision):
    frameCount = 0

elif (collision):
    if (SuperCharacter and sprite == cactus):
        frameCount = 1
        if(frameCount == 1):
            SuperCharacter = False

    elif (sprite == cactus and frameCount == 0):
        endGame()


    elif (sprite == star):
        SuperCharacter = True
```

Adding the 1 to the frameCount basically protected the character from an accidental endGame() until the collision was no longer true and then frameCount was back to zero.